# replace values in text from json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

I have an JSON-file which looks like this:

```
[
   {
        "typ":"alle",
        "id":1,
        "detailMode":"heute",
        "bedingung":[
            "evk_gebaeude",
            "evk_durchschnitt"
        ],
        "kurzerText":"Energieverbrauchskennwert '+relation+' TU Durchschnitt",
        "relation_Positiv":"liegt niedriger als der",
        "relation_Neutral":"liegt niedriger im",
        "relation_Negativ":"liegt höher als der"
    }
]
```

Now I want use the text in "kurzerText" and replace '+relation+' with relation_Positiv, relation_Neutral or relation_Negativ.

I could probably do that with regular Expressions, but I wondered if there is a easier solution?
I'm using javascript and jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `String.replace()` function like this:

```
var modifiedString = kurzerText.replace("'+relation+'", newValue);
```

[String.replace() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)